# Python pyqt: background images

Tags: python, image, qt

I'm using Python (2.7.3) and Qt designer (4.8.2) in Windows 7, and I'm new'ish to Qt designer:

**How may I create a background image within a Form widget in Qt designer?**

It doesn't matter if this takes up the entire screen or an area of the form (as demonstrated below). What I do need however is to superimpose objects such as QLineEdits and/or QLCDNumbers.

Ideally, I'd do this within Qt and not at run-time (a point and click solution would be a perfect for me).

I have generated this image in gimp quickly to demonstrate what I mean:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Found solution here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pzzccU9mErg [from 00:06:00 to 00:08:00]

Steps:

1/ Within Qt designer position a Qlabel within your widget

2/ Delete text in the text properties ('TextLabel' by deafult), and resize to image size wanted.

3/ Scroll to pixmap property and select intended image;  click scaledContents is wanted

you'll now see your image within the widget

Comment: This was exactly what I needed and it worked perfectly.  I've not seen this QLabel technique described elsewhere yet.